# why use different date format makes different result in same date?

Tags: java

I try to use current date in date formats but when I use different date formats this makes different results..at first I used this code:

```
private String getTodayDateString() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    return Integer.toString(month);
}
```

and this return me 5 for result for month.
but when I use this code:

```
private String getTodayDateString2() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

function returns me 14/6/2016 and this means month is calculated 6 in this dateformat.why?where is the problem?

Comment: because months in Calendar interface are 0 based (which is stated in the documentation)

Comment: 0 means first month?!!!!!

Comment: first month is `Calendar.JANUARY` ... you shouldn't worry if it 0 or bazillion

Comment: Always read the docs. From the docs for `Calendar.MONTH`: "Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year."

Comment: Hint: read javadoc. And other documentation. That java util Calendar stuff is **not** fit to be dealt with by "common sense" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

months in calender starts from 0

0 =january

11=december

if you see the source code of Calendar class you will find `public final static int JANUARY = 0;`

similarily for december `public final static int DECEMBER = 11;`
Check the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.0JANUARY) here